# How to integrate springboot dependency log4j with Pivotal Cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am working on PCF, so the application which I will be deploying in PCF needs files which could be external files, like log4j2spring.xml

How can I provide these files to PCF?

( This is how we are providing in our application: `logging.config=classpath:config/log4j2-spring.xml`)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an Enterprise world, the **logs** that are needed to be configured within in PCF Containers are streamed to any log-analyzer tool, like **Papertrail** or **splunk**

You should not specify any such path in logging.config, given the fact that PCF Containers can be trashed for any valid purposes, like, scaling up the app - restarting the app or whatsoever it is ..

So : Write your logs to `stdout` / `stderr` and then read those logs using `cf logs <app_name>` command. Ideal case is to have your logs streamed to any log-viewing tool

Comment: OKay thanks.So according to my understanding I have two opitons i.e.  1) using stdout/stderr and then use cf logs <app_name > so here i will have to remove all log4j logging statememnts and their configurations right?    2) using tool like papertrial and splunk  but how to use them ?

Comment: Correct. You are right

Comment: `syslog` configurations can be seen here -> https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/log-management.html

Comment: Okay Thanks a lot for your precious time and help.

Comment: But i have one doubt our code is too large and it is difficult to fing logging statements and replace with stdout and stderr so what can we do here

Comment: your `Log4j` should be configured to drop all its logs to `Standard Out` and `Standard Error` . You can google out on how to do this configuration in `Log4J` . https://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/

Comment: yes  and how to provide  logging.config=classpath:config/log4j2-spring.xml this .xml file in pcf

Comment: Do not store any `File` in PCF. Have that as part of your `Jar file`

Comment: Ya but how to have it as a part if Jar file, Actually I am working first time on PCF so.

Comment: You are asking a question that only the person who have `Architected` the application can answer. Its an Architecture-Question. I recommend you raising a seperate thread with all the necessary details...

Comment: To run an application on PCF, it must be at-least cloud friendly. That means, it must meet atleast 6 of the [12 factors principles](https://12factor.net). They are II, III, IV, VI, VII, XI. This is the least minimum. Ideally, you want all 12. 
Without refactoring your app to satisfy these, you cannot run it on PCF. If you cannot refactor, then you should be looking at another solution like Kubernetes (K8S).